# Parameter encoding (quotes and space character)

Tags: javascript, php, encoding

So I'm sending a string parameter to javascript function, and the problem is space characters and/or quotes. I can have either one working, but can't figure out how to get both ways to work at the same time.

I left encodeURIComponent and decodeURIComponent to my example as I currently use them to deal with spaces.

Javascript:

```
function alertTitle(title){
    alert(decodeURIComponent(title));
}
```

PHP:

```
//...fetching from MySQL
$title = $row['title'];

//If $title content is wrapped in single or double quotes, this will do:
$title = str_replace("\"","&quot;",$row['title']);
//But if it's not, and has spaces, I have to wrap it in quotes for encodeURIComponent:
$title = '\''.$row['title'].'\''; 
//And that obviously gives error in encodeURIComponent if $title happens already to have
// single quotes

//..And sending $title to javascript:
echo '<a onclick="alertTitle(encodeURIComponent('.$title.'));" href="#">Alert</a>';
```

So somehow I need to escape single quotes also, or then come up with some very different approach.
But this is already so close, so I wish I have just missed something simple.

$title might be anykind of the following examples:

> "Title"
>
> "Title with spaces"
>
> 'Title'
>
> 'Title' with "all combined"
>
> Title "Blaablaa" here

And so on.

All hints are more than welcome. Thanks!

Comment: `echo json_encode($title)`, and if necessary, run that through htmlspecialchars() as well.

Comment: Thanks Marc! Using both of them did the job perfectly! Damn, how simple!

Answer (score 0):

Just add a pre-replace using single quotes :)

```
//...fetching from MySQL
$title = $row['title'];

//If $title content is wrapped in single or double quotes, this will do:
$title = str_replace("\"","&quot;",$row['title']);
$title = str_replace("\'","&#39;",$row['title']);

//But if it's not, and has spaces, I have to wrap it in quotes for encodeURIComponent:
$title = '\''.$row['title'].'\''; 
//And that obviously gives error in encodeURIComponent if $title happens already to have
// single quotes

//..And sending $title to javascript:
echo '<a onclick="alertTitle(encodeURIComponent('.$title.'));" href="#">Alert</a>';
```

Comment: Actually tried this one too at some point, but for some reason it didn't help. :( Luckily Marc's way worked perfectly